# Xamarin.Forms Acquire Storage Permission Without Involving User

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, storage

We are building a Xamarin.Forms application for use in an industrial, not public, environment on an Android 10 API 29 device.

Is there a way to have the application granted storage permissions without having to ask the user for permission each time the application is started?

So far all we have found is causing a pop-up to be displayed requiring user interaction.

Comment: For what do you need that permission? And it has to be granted only one time. Not at every restart.

Comment: We need to be able to access application-specific data files.

Comment: Which kind of access? And where are those files? Keep it vague please ;-)

Answer (score 0):

We needed to load some text data files into a folder on the Android device from the Windows 10 development platform for use by the Android app.  But we could not access those text data files from the Android app.

After attaching the Android device to the Windows 10 development platform, Windows Explorer shows

```
Internal Shared Storage
```

as the root of storage on the device.

The use of "Internal" in the label can be misleading, as this is the root of all storage, including the so-called "emulated" external storage.  The "internal storage" folders are not visible on Windows 10.

The following are the steps we took to be able to access the files:

Step 1:
Using Windows Explorer, create a folder in

```
This PC\ANDROID_DEVICE_NAME\Internal shared storage\Android\data
```

where you want to place your data .  In our case it looked like

```
This PC\ANDROID_DEVICE_NAME\Internal shared storage\Android\data\com.my_app_name.configuration
```

and then copy your text data files into that folder.  (ANDROID_DEVICE_NAME depends on your device.)

Step 2:
On the Android device, under

```
Settings > Apps & notifications > Advanced > Permission manager > Storage > my_app_name
```

ensure "Allow" is selected (rather than "Deny").

Step 3:
Ensure you have the following in your project AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Step 4:

In your code, create the complete path to the file named "example.txt" using

```
System.IO.Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my_app_name.configuration", "example.txt")
```

Use the result of the Combine method to access your text data file.

Comment: If you just want use the `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my_app_name.configuration`, you don't have to request the storage permission. The storage permission is used to access the public folder such as the Donwload/Document and so on.

Comment: Liyun: No, it doesn't.  The exception System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my_app_name.configuration/my_text_file.txt" is denied.' is still thrown.

Is it possible that there are device settings that prevent or allow this to happen?

Comment: I have testes, I can write the file in this path without the storage permission.

Comment: Liyun: Thank you for the follow-up.  There has to be some environmental issue in play then with our device.  The application throws the exception even after following steps 1 through 4 above.  Our device is Android 10 API 29.